# How Can I handle Error sequence in WSO2ESB

Tags: wso2, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-esb

i want handle error using fault sequence but i wish to customize it with delete operation 
my scenario is while i am inserting in 2 tables if error occurred in 2nd table insertion i need to delete 1 st row insertion also my config is below

```
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="ErrorHandling" transports="https,http" statistics="disable" trace="disable" startOnLoad="true">
   <target >
      <inSequence onError="fault">
         <property name="eno" expression="//eno/text()" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
         <property name="ename" expression="//ename/text()" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
         <property name="esal" expression="//esal/text()" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
         <property name="deptname" expression="//deptname/text()" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
         <property name="deptid" expression="//deptid/text()" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
         <payloadFactory>
            <format>
               <p:insert_emp_operation xmlns:p="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">
                  <xs:eno xmlns:xs="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">$1</xs:eno>
                  <xs:ename xmlns:xs="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">$2</xs:ename>
                  <xs:esal xmlns:xs="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">$3</xs:esal>
               </p:insert_emp_operation>
            </format>
            <args>
               <arg expression="get-property('eno')"/>
               <arg expression="get-property('ename')"/>
               <arg expression="get-property('esal')"/>
            </args>
         </payloadFactory>
         <send receive="Error_Seq">
            <endpoint>
               <address uri="http://localhost:9764/services/emp_DataService/" format="soap11"/>
            </endpoint>
         </send>
         <log level="full"/>
      </inSequence>
      <outSequence  onError="fault">
         <send/>
         <log level="full"/>
      </outSequence>
   </target>
   <description></description>
</proxy>
```

and sequence is like this

```
<sequence xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="Error_Seq" onError="fault">
   <property xmlns:f="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice" xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" name="ID" expression="//f:ID/text()" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
   <log>
      <property xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" name="faisal" expression="get-property('ID')"/>
   </log>
   <payloadFactory>
      <format>
         <p:insert_dept_operation xmlns:p="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">
            <xs:deptno xmlns:xs="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">$1</xs:deptno>
            <xs:deptname xmlns:xs="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">$2</xs:deptname>
            <xs:deptid xmlns:xs="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">$3</xs:deptid>
         </p:insert_dept_operation>
      </format>
      <args>
         <arg xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" expression="get-property('ID')"/>
         <arg xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" expression="get-property('deptname')"/>
         <arg xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" expression="get-property('deptid')"/>
      </args>
   </payloadFactory>
   <send>
      <endpoint>
         <address uri="http://localhost:9764/services/dept_DataService/" format="soap11"/>
      </endpoint>
   </send>
</sequence>
```

fault sequenceis like this

```
<sequence xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="fault">
   <property xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" name="ID" expression="get-property('ID')" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
   <log level="full">
      <property name="MESSAGE" value="Executing default 'fault' sequence"/>
      <property xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" name="ERROR_CODE" expression="get-property('ERROR_CODE')"/>
      <property xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" name="ERROR_MESSAGE" expression="get-property('ERROR_MESSAGE')"/>
      <property xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" name="Property" expression="get-property('ID')"/>
   </log>
   <payloadFactory>
      <format>
         <p:Delete_Op xmlns:p="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">
            <xs:eno xmlns:xs="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">$1</xs:eno>
         </p:Delete_Op>
      </format>
   </payloadFactory>
   <send>
      <endpoint>
         <address uri="http://localhost:9764/services/dept_DataService/" format="soap11"/>
      </endpoint>
   </send>
</sequence>
```

but its not working its working while the DSS Is in OFF mode let me know when DSS is In Running mode how to delete the 1st table row

Answer (score 0):

In your scenario when update fails at DSS, it will send back a SOAP fault to the ESB. 
Since ESB this is still just another message response, and it will not goto the fault sequence, unless you explicitly check the message and do the necessary actions. 
So you have to declare comming message is a SOAP_FAULT so you hace to say it is a SOAP_FAULT and force it to error sequance. This is explained in [1].

[1] http://maharachchi.blogspot.com/2012/09/now-you-can-send-soapfaults-to-fault.html

Comment: i have a 4 sequences those are inserting in different 4 tables . so i can define this property in every sequence else just in insequence only .

Comment: This applies to every service call which you are expecting to call to DSS service which will execute the query. If you have 4 DSS operations refering 4 tables and called by 4 sequences in ESB yes you need to add for all four sequences.

Comment: thanx a lot dharshana .my scenario is i am using 3 tables to insert..and using Returned genrated key for every insertion..my 1st insertion done succesfully and returned a key using that one i am inserting data into 2nd table but error violated in 2nd table.i want rollback 1st table data also..how we can do this

Comment: you can add a rollback query for another DSS operation and based on the failed sequence you can refer a sequence which will refer the dss service. You can extract the id from the response of the 1st message. Its all Synapse

Comment: thanx..ya i am doing same as per your guidance like i am taking property of id in fault sequence and firing delete query against DB using DBReport mediator..is it ok ..one more thing little bit iterate mediator is not working for this xpath :   <property name="ReadingsLiteTaildto expression="//ReadingsLiteTaildto /><iterate continueParent="true"
                  id="Readings"
                  expression="get-property('ReadingsLiteTaildto')"> BUT its working for this :<iterate continueParent="true"
                  id="Readings"
                  expression="//ReadingsLiteTaildto">