# how to handle a transaction in wso2esb or wso2dss with postgressql

Tags: wso2, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-esb

I want to know a bit more about DSS transaction handling. I've been reading up on boxcarring and distributed transactions, but that's not what I'm looking for. Boxcarring is statefull (the client needs to maintain a session) and my transaction is within the same database and not distributed.

I'm looking for a solution to the following problem/challenge: - I have a set of related table. They are related by primary/foreign key relations. I need to update/insert objects in the related tables. Can I do this in a set of nested update queries? And if so, what happens when one of the updates fails? Will all the inserted/updated objects rolled back? (I'm using the postgres datbase)

i inserted into 1st table and get a returnedkey value which is one of the future of wso2dss and using that key i am inserting into 2nd table also and getting one more key using that inserting one more time my insertion is ok while i am inserting 
my issue is if i am inserting in duplicate data into 2nd table it will thorough error in that case my 1st table row could be rollback..how we can do this in wso2dss or wso2esb

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You can use Stored procedure instead nested query. you can get idea how to execute stored procedures in dss by [1].

[1].http://blog.shelan.org/2012/03/how-to-call-mysql-stored-procedures.html

Thank You,
Dharshana.

Comment: thanx for  replay. i hope u can clarify my doubt my issue is how to rollback a transaction in wso2esb or wso2dss i am using POSTGRES      http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15332501/how-can-i-handle-error-sequence-in-wso2esb

Comment: In your scenario when update fails at DSS, it will send back a SOAP fault to the ESB. 
Since ESB this is still just another message response, and it will not goto the fault sequence, unless you explicitly check the message and do the necessary actions. 
So you have to declare comming message is a SOAP_FAULT so you hace to say it is a SOAP_FAULT and force it to error sequance. This is explained in [1].

[1] http://maharachchi.blogspot.com/2012/09/now-you-can-send-soapfaults-to-fault.html

Comment: thanx a lot ..once again     can i write a delete operation in fault sequence using dbreport mediator.if error occured in esb or in dss fault sequence will be responds in that only i can write delete operation based on returned genrated key

Comment: i have a 4 sequences those are inserting in different 4 tables . so i can define this property in every sequence else just in insequence only .

Comment: This applies to every service call which you are expecting to call to DSS service which will execute the query. If you have 4 DSS operations refering 4 tables and called by 4 sequences in ESB yes you need to add for all four sequences.

Comment: thanx a lot..my scenario is i am using 3 tables to insert..and using Returned genrated key for every insertion..my 1st insertion done succesfully and returned a key using that one i am inserting data into 2nd table but error violated in 2nd table.i want rollback 1st table data also..how we can do this